# Ubuntu 16.04 Does Not detect external monitor

Tags: 16.04, external-monitor

Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting LG ultrawide external display. Currently using laptop and have LG set up as second screen. Have an nvidia GTX 1060, with what I believe to be the correct nvidia 367.44 and 670 drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is only a few hours old.  So fyi, I just applied this morning's updates to a Thinkpad with integrated graphics and external CRT.  The CRT wasn't detected after reboot.  So there may have been a recent regression.

It seems a failure to activate the monitor.  After detection has failed, if I power cycle the CRT, so it is not on standby, then detection works.  I see Linux 4.4.0-42-generic *intermittently* failing to activate during cold boot.